# Multiply read text files files don't seem to exist?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

I'm running batch jobs on a RHEL5 lustre filesystem. Many jobs (13k) read the same text file, which is used to direct each job to a different dataset. The code looks like this:

```
with open('dataset-paths.txt') as txt_file: 
    dataset_location = txt_file.readlines()[job_number].strip()
```

But for some fraction of my jobs, I get

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataset-paths.txt'
```

Is it not possible to open the same text file from multiple processes at the same time? What else could cause this?

Comment: Does anything ever modify or delete the file?

Comment: @user2357112 no, nothing changes the file, the file is only used within that `with` block

Answer (score 1):

Just a "random guess", maybe to error message is just misleading?

Remember there is a limit on the number of opened files -- or to be precise of the number of file descriptors. Given the high number of process involved, it is quite possible that at some point during execution that limit is reached...

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives me 829173, which is far more than the number of jobs I'm running (about 18k)

Comment: @Shep I'm not a specialist of that kind of stuff, but as far as I remember, there is a "system" limit, as well as par user/per group/per process group limit(s). On my system, `ulimit -Hn -Sn` reports only 1024 max open files. Whereas `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is way beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue why that is happening, maybe locks on the file or too many open file handles. But apply this when you open/interact with your file. It basically keeps trying until there is no errors.

```
result = None
while result is None:
    try:
        # connect perform I/O
        result = get_data(...)
    except:
         pass
```

Comment: tried something like this... no luck, it's like the file is missing for the duration of the job

Comment: @Shep Have you tried to add a timeout (`time.sleep(s)`)? Maybe the file handles need time to be removed or something. I would say about 2 seconds should do the job, give it a try.

Comment: yeah, I tried having it check 100 times with a 5 second timeout

Comment: no, same problem. I'm looking into limiting the number of simultanious jobs (although I don't really know why that would help).

Comment: Note I can reproduce this error [without even using python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18253796/915501)

Comment: @Shep Can you add a small chunk of code to determine if the directory exists?

Comment: @Shep also try to add this condition `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you should need 13K jobs all reading the same file just to pick out one line:

```
dataset_location = txt_file.readlines()[job_number].strip()
```

It would be more efficient to read the file once, and pass `dataset_location` to each of the 13k jobs as an argument.

Comment: sure, this would work if the jobs were spawned in python, but they are spawned from a bash script that can only vary an integer between jobs... it's ugly, but this is the only working solution I could come up with